# GET parameters missing on ZF2

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I'm trying to build a controller which function is to get a 'external' URL and translate it to an internal URL. The external URL is like the following: `http://localhost/dir/public/api?entity=11` and the URL internal is like: `http://localhost/dir/public/en/entity/1254`. My module.conf.php is like this:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'api' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/api',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Extranet\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'api',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '[/:locale]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'locale' => 'ca|es|en',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Extranet\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'Entity',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'locale' => 'ca',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '[/:controller[/:id]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '(?!intranet)(?!api)([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)',
                            'id' => '[a-z0-9]+',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Extranet\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

The problem is that when i write on my controller : `$this->params()->fromQuery();` this params are empty and I does not understand why, because if I write some var_dump() in my code, it works!. I'm desperated.

Thanks

Comment: So the only problem is the missing Query-param on `/api`, right? Btw there is no need for `Segment` there, because of no Route-params - use `Literal` instead.

Comment: Yes, the problem is when I try `/api?entity=25` that in my controller this query parameter (entity) is lost (I'm trying like: `$this->getRequest()->getQuery(null, null)->toArray()`). But if down of this line I write a var_dump with this line, It works! I don't understand why happens.

Comment: What happens when you do `$entity = $this->params()->fromQuery('entity'); var_dump($entity);die();`?

Comment: what class does your ExtranetController extend?

Comment: If i write `$entity = $this->params()->fromQuery('entity'); ` I have the same problem.

Comment: I don't have a class called ExtranetController